# Meteor erro no lado do cliente, alguém sabe o que é isso?

Tags: node.js, meteorjs

> The connection to ws://localhost:3000/sockjs/622/u2zaukpp/websocket
>   was interrupted while the page was loading.

A mensagem de erro diz que o sockjs 'websocket' foi interrompido enquanto a página carregava, gostaria de saber porque está acontecendo isso, eu não tenho ideia, desde já agradeço.

Comment: Que aplicação você estava usando? O que é que existe rodando na porta 3000 do seu host? O mais provável é que seja lá qual for a aplicação que estava rodando lá, ela foi derrubada e com isso a página no seu navegador que a utilizava ficou abandonada.

Comment: é o nodejs, o meteor é um framework pra ele.